# getting None from scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, robots.txt

As part of my studies about python, I try to **scrape** mail.ru main page
the news lines

I have allowed to crawl, I added custom user agent. I have different xpath location, cant get anything, just empty list.

```
import scrapy

class TestmailspidetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'testmailspidet'
    allowed_domains = ['mail.ru']
    start_urls = ['http://mail.ru/']

    def parse(self, response):
   
    yield {
        'testing':response.xpath('//span[@class="i-link-deco i-inline"][position()=1]').extract_first()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's forbidden by robots.txt (https://mail.ru/robots.txt). If you still want to scrape it, you'll have to set ROBOTSTXT_OBEY to False. You can include this as follows:

```
custom_settings = {
    'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
}
```

Furthermore, the xpath doesn't give any results - probably because the content is loaded dynamically. You can check with scrapy shell what the html-page looks like that scrapy sees like this: `scrapy shell -s ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False "http://mail.ru/"`.
The xpath that gets you the titles can then be constructed as follows: `//*[@id="news:main:list"]//*[@class="news__list__item__link__text"]/text()`.

Comment: tnx for answer. i have  this line in settings - ROBOTSTXT_OBEY: False

Comment: Then the xpath might need to be changed. Probably the content is loaded dynamically. The following xpath seems to work for me though: `//*[@id="news:main:list"]//*[@class="news__list__item__link__text"]/text()`

Comment: tnx, it did work, would u pls explain me the xpath ?

Comment: I first checked how scrapy sees the page with scrapy shell: `scrapy shell -s ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False "http://mail.ru/"`. With `view(response)` you can checkout the html-page. There you can see the content you want to scrape is under id 'news:main:list'. The titles you want as output are under this id, specifically under the class tag 'news__list__item__link__text'